# Add Custom Contact row in Phonebook like Whatsapp

Tags: android, android-contacts, account, phonebook

Basically what I need to achieve is very clear but I am having many doubts in my implementation. I went through R & D about this topic but didn't find satisfied answer. Hope you guys will understand me and help me further.

So here is screen shot for what I want to do:

Contact detail page

[image]

What I did till now:

Manifest.xml

```
        <activity
            android:name=".AddCardActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <!--<data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.ccc.in.businesscard" />-->
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".customcontact.AccountAuthenticatorService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":auth">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
                android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".customcontact.ContactsSyncAdapterService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":contacts">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                android:resource="@xml/sync_contacts" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.provider.CONTACTS_STRUCTURE"
                android:resource="@xml/contacts" />
        </service>
```

Here in intent-filter tag should I need to define `mime-type`? If I define `mime-type` as above my application is not being listed in Application list of device.

Permissions in Manifest.XML:

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS"
        android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
```

authenticator.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountPreferences="@xml/account_preferences"
    android:accountType="ccc.in.businesscard.account"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:smallIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

account_preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--<PreferenceCategory-->
        <!--android:title="General Settings" />-->

    <!--<PreferenceScreen-->
        <!--android:key="account_settings"-->
        <!--android:title="Account Settings"-->
        <!--android:summary="Sync frequency, notifications, etc.">-->
        <!--<intent-->
            <!--android:action="fm.last.android.activity.Preferences.ACCOUNT_SETUP"-->
            <!--android:targetPackage="fm.last.android"-->
            <!--android:targetClass="fm.last.android.activity.Preferences" />-->
    <!--</PreferenceScreen>-->
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Don't know much about this file.

sync_contacts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="ccc.in.businesscard.account"
    android:contentAuthority="com.android.contacts"
    android:supportsUploading="false" />
```

contacts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContactsSource xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ContactsDataKind
        android:detailColumn="data3"
        android:detailSocialSummary="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.ccc.in.businesscard"
        android:summaryColumn="data2"/>
</ContactsSource>
```

AddCardActivity.java

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_card);

        addAccount("MyNewServiceNumber", "123456");
    }



private void addAccount(String userName, String password) {
        Account account = new Account(userName, getString(R.string.ACCOUNT_TYPE));
        AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("Mobile", "+911111111111");
        boolean accountCreated = am.addAccountExplicitly(account, password, bundle);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            if (accountCreated) {  //Pass the new account back to the account manager
                AccountAuthenticatorResponse response = extras.getParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE);
                Bundle result = new Bundle();
                result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, userName);
                result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, getString(R.string.ACCOUNT_TYPE));
                response.onResult(result);
            }
        }
        addContactTag(account,"+911111111111");
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Account added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

 public void addContactTag(Account account, String number) {

        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operationList = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

        //  Create our RawContact
        ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
        operationList.add(builder.build());

        //  Create a Data record of common type 'Phone' for our RawContact
        builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, number);
        operationList.add(builder.build());


        builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
        builder.withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.ccc.in.businesscard");
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1, number);
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA2, "ourservice user");
        builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA3, "Go to ourservice profile");
        operationList.add(builder.build());


        try {
            ContentResolver mContentResolver = getContentResolver();
            mContentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, operationList);
            Log.d("addContactTag", "addContact batch applied");
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Contact added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("addContactTag", "Something went wrong during creation! " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is it. Let me know where I am doing wrong? Some doubts I faced:

1. Why we need to add Account in device Settings?
2. I can see that my code is only to add new record. How can I update specific contact to add custom row.

Till now with above code, my application is only listed in Accounts section in Settings menu. I want to add custom row in my contact list who are using my application.

Please help me with this scenario. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add whatsapp like options to contact whenever the is a new contact added to Contacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42525615/how-to-add-whatsapp-like-options-to-contact-whenever-the-is-a-new-contact-added)

Comment: you need to either (1) edit an existing record by adding a custom data row with your own mimetype, or (2) create a new RawContact with your data row and mimetype, and then *programatically* aggregate that new Raw with the existing Raw - see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40684028/why-wont-contacts-aggregate/40869351#40869351

Comment: @marmor Can you please check this similar issue- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52905223/app-added-in-accounts-with-contact-sync-option-but-not-showing-in-contact-detail?