# Add Entries like Telegram/Whatsapp to Contacts in android

Tags: android

I want to add a simple entry for my app in Contacts like Telegram or whatspp.
[Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47667738/add-custom-contact-row-in-phonebook-like-whatsapp)

I've read about `SyncAdapter` and `Authenticator`.

I haven't a cloud service or something so I don't need an Authenticator, but it seems that I must have one.

I have a `List<ContactItem>`, each ContactItem has:

```java
    private final long contactId;
    private final String phoneNumber;
    private final String phoneNumberFormatted;
    private final String contactName;
    private final boolean isContactSaved;
    private final Uri contactImage;
    private final boolean defaultIcon;
    private final String lookupKey;
    private final Uri lookupUri;
    private final int contactType;
    private int count;
```

I get all things I need from user's contact.

I want to add a shortcut for each contact in my List (like Telegram) that opens my ContactActivity and I should pass to this activity lookupKey and contactId.

I've read some example/tutorial but I can't add this entry to contact.
Actually I'm in the some condition of linked question, every question like mine isn't answered with a correct way to do this...